# Debugging asp .NET Core 5 beta in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-webapps

Is it possible to debug an asp .net core 5 beta web app running on azure?  I've been getting this error since I tried to do this.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710023): Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named 'blahblahblah.azurewebsites.net'.  The connection with the remote endpoint was terminated.

at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Operations.IDebuggerInternal120.ConnectToServer(String szServerName, VsDebugRemoteConnectOptions[] pConnectOptions, CONNECT_REASON ConnectReason, Int32 fIncrementUsageCount, IDebugCoreServer3& ppServer)
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.VS.Operations.RemoteDiagnosticsSessionBase`1.ConnectToServer(String site, String user, String password)

Comment: I should also add that my build is debug, my app service is set for remote debugging, and my publishing type is set to self contained.  IIRC, self contained puts everything into a directory and deploys it to azure.  I think all are correct for trying to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar challenges on .netcore5 with exact same error message. I've checked all the criteria like DEBUG build, having the right App Service Plan Level, ensuring remote debug is enabled in Azure, using both Cloud Explorer as well as the classic Attach Process, toggling Deployment mode (framework vs. self contained) even ensuring ensuring matches of 32 vs 64 bit server/client and running VS2019 in admin mode.

Been chasing this all weekend but am planning to just set it aside and try again when .net5 has moved out of (early access) status

Comment: I hope that some of this helps.  IIRC, and it has been a while since I had this issue so take this for what it is worth, the problem was that I had an add-in in VS that was causing a certificate error/conflict.  I'm sorry, but I don't remember which that it was.  When I uninstalled the VS add-in, remote debugging started to work.  fyi, remote debugging is not 100% reliable.  It is communicating over the public internet, so little hiccups are not surprising.  :-/